# JavaScript - Validate date input so it's only either current or the future

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I'm trying to validate a date input box so that it only accepts the current or future dates. So far I've been struggling to find answers which definitively does this.

Here is the HTML for the input box, excluding the `<form>` tags:

```
<p>
   <label>Date:</label>
   <br>
   <input type="number" name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" onchange="checkDate()">
</p>
<div id="datewarn"></div>
```

Here is JavaScript code that I'm using which validates whether the input is in the format DD/MM/YYYY and that the numbers entered in are valid calender numbers, but this still accepts past dates.

```
function checkDate() {
    var valid = true;
    var redate = /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](0[1-9]|1[012])[\/](19|20)\d\d/;

    if (!redate.test(document.bookingsform.date.value)) {
        document.bookingsform.date.style.border = "1px solid red";
        document.getElementById("datewarn").innerHTML = "Enter a date in the format DD/MM/YYYY.";
        document.bookingsform.date.title = "Please enter a date in the format DD/MM/YYYY.";
        document.getElementById("datewarn").style.display = "block";
        valid = false;
    } else {
        document.bookingsform.date.style.border = "1px inset #EBE9ED";
        document.bookingsform.date.style.borderRadius = "2px";
        document.getElementById("datewarn").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

The research that I have done suggests using the date.js library? Is this an inbuilt library or this something I have to get?

This can only be JavaScript, no jQuery.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to add the RegEx variable.

Comment: Use input type date instead.

Comment: That doesn't work on Firefox, and Chrome only does YYYY-MM-DD. W3C Validator says that this Input Type doesn't work on all browsers. I'd rather stay away from it.

Comment: Yeah, input type number doesn't work in all browsers too but one day it will. If you are afraid of browser incompatibility use input type `text` instead.

Comment: True, but the Validator doesn't give a warning for number, whereas date does.

Comment: You can use `novalidate` attribute if you don't want warnings and validate everything with your current (or improved) regular expression.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a function to tell, if the date you are entering is future date or not.

**JS Function and use example:**

```
const isFutureDate = (idate) =>{
    let today = new Date().getTime();
        idate = idate.split("/");
    
    idate = new Date(idate[2], idate[1] - 1, idate[0]).getTime();
    return (today - idate) < 0;
}

// Demo example
console.log(isFutureDate("02/03/3014")); // true
console.log(isFutureDate("01/01/2014")); // false
```

**Here is implementation for you:**

```
function checkDate(){
    var idate = document.getElementById("date"),
        resultDiv = document.getElementById("datewarn"),
        dateReg = /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](0[1-9]|1[012])[\/]201[4-9]|20[2-9][0-9]/;
    
    if(!dateReg.test(idate.value)){
        resultDiv.innerHTML = "Invalid date!";
        resultDiv.style.color = "red";
        return;            
    } 

    if(isFutureDate(idate.value)){
        resultDiv.innerHTML = "Entered date is a future date";
        resultDiv.style.color = "red";
    } else {
        resultDiv.innerHTML = "It's a valid date";
        resultDiv.style.color = "green";
    }
}
```

**test it with this HTML:**

```
<p>
    <label>Date:</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" onkeyup="checkDate()" />
</p>
<div id="datewarn"></div>
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/LaL9W/5/): http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/LaL9W/5/

Comment: Doesn't work. Try with `isFutureDate("01/12/2014");` - because your date is interpreted as MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: yep, it works but you still can't tell if the user intended 02/03/2014 or 03/02/2014... Plain text fields for dates means having this problem, and there's no way to solve it.

Comment: that is why placeholder (DD/MM/YYYY) is there to enter the date in what format. There is no need to solve anything.

Comment: Infact this is not the headache for the person who asked the question and also changing the input type doesnt affects the function I have written.. isn't it?

Comment: No but using my function makes all the RegEx stuff totally useless :)

Comment: Also, placeholders won't prevent this kind of errors from users. It will diminish them, but UX studies state that lots of errors remain.

Comment: And for the headache part, well... (correctly) programming involves a lot of headaches much more aching than this one.

Comment: I think that is very different approach of thing this. If somebody wants to do this in one input, that fine. Can be done. Also, input type DATE doesn't even allows you to enter a date in your format. So, the thing is how you fix the problem, not to do it in another way. That is a very different thing.

Comment: Also I believe your function is solution of a very different problem than this one. :)

Comment: @AshishKumar This works, but it still accepts dates from 1900 up-to-and-including 2013. How would you reject these dates? I only want 2014 and future.

Answer (score 1):

### Working with dates from HTML forms

Working dates from plain text inputs  is not an easy problem, because of the wide range of different notations, and paradoxically, the similarities between them.

For instance, you can tell whether this is DD/MM/YYYY:

```
dateString = "24/03/1983";
```

But how about this one? Is it DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY:

```
dateString = "11/10/1998";
```

Let me tell you: **there is no way to guess**. And you can rest assured that even if you print a notice just above your field, be it in bold red blinking 28px Comic Sans MS, the user will enter the date in the format he is used to. And you can't even blame him, because you would do the same. It's just [operant conditioning behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operant_conditioning).

That's why, throughout the web, most date inputs are made through 3 drop-down lists: day, month, year.

### Telling if the input is in the past or not

Once you do that, and assuming that your values are:

```
var day = document.bookingsform.date.day.value
var month = document.bookingsform.date.month.value
var year = document.bookingsform.date.year.value
```

You are now able to perform your test:

```
inputTime = new Date(year + "/" + month + "/" + day).getTime();

// then you can do this:

currentDate = new Date;
currentDate.setHours(0);
currentDate.setMinutes(0);
currentDate.setSeconds(0);

currentTime = currentDate.getTime();

notInPast = (inputTime - currentTime < 1000);

// or this:

currentTime = Math.round((new Date).getTime() / 86400000) * 86400000;

notInPast = (inputTime >= currentTime);
```

The part with `setHours()` etc is necessary because when you start a new `Date` object given DD/MM/YYYY, JavaScript will assume that the time for this `Date` is 00:00. Whereas the time for the current `Date` (obtained with `new Date`) is the current time.

So if you don't perform this kind of correction, you form will always tell that today's DD/MM/YYYY is in the past. Which you don't want.

Comment: I didn't think of it like that, thanks for putting that out there. But one question, this website is for a restaurant in the UK, so surely the people who access the website will only be those from the UK and these people are all conditioned to write the date in the format DD/MM/YYYY?

Comment: @RoyalSwish what about an American tourist that wants to make a reservation and keeps banging his head upon your form because it doesn't validate his MM/DD/YYYY input, so that finally he gets bored and changes his mind, planning watching TV instead of eating out?

Comment: Fair enough, and last thing, are `inputTime`, `currentTime`, and `notInPast` variables?

Comment: @RoyalSwish yes they are - I didn't declare them to focus on the business logic part in my answer, but I leave this functional job as an exercise for the reader :)