# Javascript function to check if a date entered in the "datetime" form field is not a past date and only today's or some future date

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use date-time field in HTML as below. However I want to use that value to check that the date is either today's or a future date and not a past date.

I checked other questions on somewhat similar topic but they didn't really help in any way. Is there any way one can extract date from date-time field because when we use the value of the field, we get numbers and alphabets which do not make any sense to me.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checknum() 
{
var num_ch=document.forms["bookticketpage"]["childrens"].value;
var num_tk=document.forms["bookticketpage"]["tickets"].value;
if(num_ch > num_tk)
{
alert("No of tickets should be greater than the no of children");
}
}
function calcfare()
{
var tick = document.forms["bookticketpage"]["tickets"].value;
var ch=document.forms["bookticketpage"]["childrens"].value;
var total = (tick-ch)*200 + ch*100;
alert("Your approximate ticket amount is " + total + " INR");
}
</script>
<body>
<style type="text/css" >
.item img { 
height: 200px; 
width: 200px; 
-webkit-transition: all 2s ease; 
-moz-transition: all 2s ease;
-ms-transition: all 2s ease;
transition: all 2s ease; } 
.item img:hover 
{
width: 300px; 
height: 300px;
}
</style>
<form name="bookticketpage" action="thankyou.html" method="post">
<div>
<h2><b>Movie Ticket Booking</b></h2>
<table>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="username">Name</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter the name" size="20" 
required pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+">
</td>
</tr>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="moviename">Movie Name</label>
</td>
<td>
<datalist id="movies">
    <option value="Irada"></option>
    <option value="Rangoon"></option>
    <option value="Logan"></option>
    <option value="Fist Fight"></option>
</datalist>
<input list="movies" name="moviename" size="20" required="true"/>
</td>
</tr>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------> 
<tr>
<td>
<label for="circle">Circle</label>
</td>
<td>
<datalist id="circles">
    <option value="Silver"></option>
    <option value="Gold"></option>
    <option value="Platinum"></option>
</datalist>
<input list="circles" name="circle" size="20" required="true"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="phone">Phone no</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Mobile # here" required 
pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" >
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="showdate">Show date and time</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type = "datetime-local" name="showdate required="true"">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="tickets">No of tickets</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="tickets" size="20" min="1" max="10" 
required="true">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label for="childrens">No of childrens</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="childrens" size="20" min="1" max="5" 
required="true">
</td>
</tr>
<!------------------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>
<label for="Book My Show"><input type = "submit" value ="Book My Show" 
onClick="checknum(); calcfare();"/></label>
</td>
<td>
<label for="reset"><input type="reset" value="Reset"/></label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div class="item">
<img src="contactus.jpg" width="254" height="54">

<div class="item-overlay top"></div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (new Date(somedatefield.value)).getTime() then check its range

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Validate date input so it's only either current or the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499843/javascript-validate-date-input-so-its-only-either-current-or-the-future)

Comment: @Jonas w it's a little different, I want user to input a past date so that he can get a alert regarding that. I will try out  
(new Date(somedatefield.value)).getTime() once but I do not want time, I only want to operate on dates. Will it still work? I will try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function myFunction(){
  var inputDate = new Date(document.getElementById("bookingday").value);
  var date = new Date();
  if(inputDate < date){
     alert("Please enter valid date");
  }else{
    alert("Valid date. Thank you");
  }
}
```

```html
Enter a booking date:<br>
<input type="datetime-local" id="bookingday"><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: thank you for your time and effort, it was exactly what I wanted. I will comment once more after trying this beacause when I tried using value of getELementbyId and compared it with new date, it wasn't working, but here on clicking Run code snippet it's working.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function setMinDate() {
  var dateInput = document.getElementById('date');
  var str = new Date().toISOString();
  console.log(str);
  str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
  dateInput.setAttribute('min', str);
  console.log(dateInput);
  
}
setMinDate();
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="party">DATE:</label>
    <input id="date"  type="datetime-local" name="partydate" >
  </form>
```

You can set the `min` attribute to your input tag
 `<input type="datetime-local" id="date" name="showdate" required=" true " />`

Comment: thank you for your time and effort. It is a novel solution, I'll keep in my mind but I wanted the user to input a past date and then get an alert. I am sorry if you didn't get that from my question and thanks.@Mr ASquare did it fine.

Comment: @definepi314 no problem man. But usually we restrict user from entering wrong date.