# How to accept only future or current time in input type='time'?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an `input` field with `type="time"`. How to make this field accept only the current or future time?

If the user enters a wrong time, a message should be displayed asking to enter the time again. Future here means upto 2 days.

Here I'm just displaying the current time using jquery.

```js
function validDate(){
  var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
  document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
}

$(function() {
  $('input[type="time"][value="now"]').each(function() {
    var d = new Date(),
        h = d.getHours(),
        m = d.getMinutes();
    if (h < 10) h = '0' + h;
    if (m < 10) m = '0' + m;
    $(this).attr({
      'value': h + ':' + m
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="validDate()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Date<span>*</span></p>
      <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="form-control input-sm " required />
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Time <span>*</span></p>
      <input type="time" value="now" name="time" id="time" class="form-control input-sm " required />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: How are you supposed to validate this if the time value can be up to two days in the future? If I enter `00:01` how are you supposed to know if I mean midnight today that's passed, or midnight tomorrow? Your logic here for validation is flawed.

Comment: Did you know that `$(document).ready(function() {});` and `$(function() {});` are the same thing? So you're basically doing `$(document).ready(function() { $(document).ready(function() {}); });`. I know this is not related to your question, but I noticed this in your code so I had to comment on it :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21499843/javascript-validate-date-input-so-its-only-either-current-or-the-future

Comment: @coder7777 did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I give an simple solution. If both value are less than current value it will alert the user.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#time").on("focusout",function(e){
                var currentTime = new Date();
                var userTime = $("#time").val().split(":"); 
                if(currentTime.getHours() > parseInt(userTime[0])){
                    alert("To old value");
                    $(this).focus();                
                }
                if(currentTime.getHours() <= parseInt(userTime[0])){
                    if(currentTime.getMinutes() > parseInt(userTime[1])){
                        alert("To old value");
                    $(this).focus();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom `AddDays()` function to get two days later and can `hide()` or `show()` the error message according to selected date value. You can implement like following.

```js
function validDate(){
  var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
  document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
}
$(function() {
  $('input[type="time"][value="now"]').each(function() {
    var d = new Date(),
        h = d.getHours(),
        m = d.getMinutes();
    if (h < 10) h = '0' + h;
    if (m < 10) m = '0' + m;
    $(this).attr({
      'value': h + ':' + m
    });
  });
});

// Your custom day addition function
function addDays (date, days) {
  const result = new Date(date)
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days)
  return result
}

$("#date").on("change",function(e){
    var val = new Date($(this).val()); // selected value
    var current = new Date(); // current date
    var futuredate = addDays(current,2) // two days later

    if(val.getTime() <= futuredate.getTime())
    {
       $("#error").hide();
    }
    else
    {  
       $("#error").show();
       $(this).val(null); // makes input default
    }    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="validDate()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Date<span>*</span></p>
      <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="form-control input-sm " required />
      <span id="error" style="display:none; color:red">Please select a date within two days</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>Time <span>*</span></p>
      <input type="time" value="now" name="time" id="time" class="form-control input-sm " required />
    </div>
</body>
```