# Displaying error message if selected time is in between the time range given in dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to show an error message if selected time range from the dropdown is between the current time.

I am having a datepicker and delivery time.For delivery time i have given some time ranges like 10-1,1-4,4-7,7-10.If the user selects today date and the time as 1-4 then it should show an validation message like the time slot is not available.

Datepicker:

```
<div><label class="delivery_date_label">' . __( "Delivery Date" ) . ': </label>

            <input type="text" id="delivery_calender_lite" name="delivery_calender_lite" class="delivery_calender_lite" style="cursor: text!important;margin-bottom:10px;" readonly/>
  </div>
```

Timepicker:

```
<div><label class="delivery-hours">' . __( "Delivery Time" ) . ': </label>
                <select id="delivery-hours" class="delivery-hours" name="delivery_hour" >
                    <option value="">'.__("Choose an hour").'</option>
                    <option value="10am-1pm">10AM-1PM</option>
                    <option value="1pm-4pm">1PM-4PM</option>
                    <option value="4pm-7pm">4PM-7PM</option>
                    <option value="7pm-10pm">7PM-10PM</option>

                </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: Which is the plugin you are using  for `datepicker` ?

Comment: This is the woocommerce one which i am working

Comment: so it's `wordpress` plugin right. ?

Comment: can you console the value of the `datepicker` so we can see what format are you getting your value.?

Comment: @JithinRajPR its a wordpress plugin

Comment: @JithinRajPR value is getting in this format 12-7-2017

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148981/discussion-between-jithin-raj-p-r-and-user8001297).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I think this will work. But you will have to use jQuery. I have used `bootstrap date picker` in it but I think it will just work fine with your plugin as well.cheers..!

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/ryrt9a2d/)**

Comment: Its not working if i select tomorrows date in your code only

Comment: I have slected timings 4-7 also its working it should not work

Comment: If i select tomorrows date and select any timing it should work right but it is displaying pop up as slot not available

Comment: @user8001297 i have fixed the bug please do check it

Comment: I need to display n invoice as delivery time- 10-12 in this format but now it is displaying as 18 in this format need to display in am and pm

Comment: @user8001297 you do one thing 'you display the text in the option' in invoice, i know this may come to this that's why I asked you before regarding the `option value`

Comment: you can `$("#delivery-hours option:selected").text();` to get the text

Comment: Which text i need  to display in the invoice we need to display as delivery time:10Am-1PM in this format if not how can the owner know the timing

Comment: where i need to add this text

Comment: Not getting you what you are saying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149000/discussion-between-jithin-raj-p-r-and-user8001297).

Comment: Now the time is 10:55 and date is 13 so i selected date as 13 and time as 10-1 range but also it is accepting it should not accept right

Comment: Now the time is 10:55 and date is 13 so i selected date as 13 and time as 10-1 range but also it is accepting it should not accept right

Comment: @user8001297 i have fixed all the bugs and updated the `JsFiddle` please do check.

Answer (score 0):

Here I give my previous solution and [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45012528/5503514). But you need to convert the select drop down value to hours and compare with it current time!If you give more details about you plugin it will helpful to solve it.

Comment: I have used " Product Delivery Date for WooCommerce - Lite" this plugin and added to select delivery time

Comment: If i close the alert box it is proceeding to add the product to cart page But it should not accept

Comment: It just for reference. I am working on your sample and you will get the updated result as soon as possible!

Comment: The one which you shared in that code if i select tomorrows date also it is displaying the alert box

Answer (score 0):

Here I give complete solution. Check this out.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="validDate()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>Date<span>*</span></p>
      <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="form-control input-sm " required />
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <label id="time" class="delivery-hours">Delivery Time</label>
                <select id="delivery-hours" class="delivery-hours" name="delivery_hour" >
                    <option value="">Choose an hour</option>
                    <option value="10am-1pm">10AM-1PM</option>
                    <option value="1pm-4pm">1PM-4PM</option>
                    <option value="4pm-7pm">4PM-7PM</option>
                    <option value="7pm-10pm">7PM-10PM</option>

                </select>
                </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function validDate(){
            var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
            document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#delivery-hours").on("change",function(e){
                var userdate = new Date($("#date").val());              
                var currentDate = new Date();
                var userdateString = userdate.getFullYear() +"-"+(userdate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+userdate.getDate();
                var currentDateString = currentDate.getFullYear() +"-"+(currentDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+currentDate.getDate();
                if(userdateString == currentDateString){
                    var userTime = $("#delivery-hours").val().split("-");   
                    var minTime = parseInt(userTime[0].replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ));
                    var maxTime = parseInt(userTime[1].replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ));
                    if(userTime[0].indexOf("pm") >=1 ){
                        minTime = minTime + 12;
                    }
                    if(userTime[1].indexOf("pm") >= 1){
                        maxTime = maxTime + 12;
                    }               
                    if(currentDate.getHours() >  minTime && currentDate.getHours() > maxTime)
                        alert("slot not avilable");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>   
</body>
```